# Retrieving values from a multidimensional array jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

There are tons of questions on multidimensional array with jQuery and Javascript here on Stack and I red them all, but what I understood I guess it's wrong 'cause it doesn't work.

I'm using a `$.ajax` function that connects to `tester2.php`. The PHP script, depending on which value the user passes (through a `<select>` menu) send different queries to the DB and always retrieves a multidimensional array like this one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => carbon
            [lvl] => 1
        )

)
```

The array is sent back via jQuery, but the problem is that I want to sent:

1. `carbon` to `<div id="txt">`
2. `1` to `<div id="level">`

I tried this ways to retrieve the single value from the multidimensional array, methods that I found here on Stack, but any of them works:

- `data[0]["name"]`
- `data[0]["name"].value`

So, do anyone knows how to retrieve the single value from a multidimensional array in jQuery?

*Note*: if I print the array using `$("#txt").html(data)` the array is there, so it is correctly called back to the HTML page.

HTML page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menuSelect").on("click", function(){
        var str = $("#menuSelect").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tester2.php",
            data: { value: str },
            success: function(data){
                    var a = data[0]["name"];
                    var b = data[0]["lvl"];
                    $("#txt").html(a);
                    $("#level").html(b);
            }
        })
    })
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="txt" style="background-color:#EF1014">
</div>

<div id="level" style="background-color:#625DDB">
</div>
```

PHP script

```
<?php
include "dbFns.php";
dbConn();

function provaAJAX($value) {
switch ($value) {
    case "0":
        $query = dbSelect("name, lvl", "productsma", "id=1", "", "", "Errore nei risultati");
        print_r($query);
        break;
    case "1":
        $query = dbSelect("name, lvl", "productsma", "id=2", "", "", "Errore nei risultati");
        print_r($query);
        break;
    case "2":
        $query = dbSelect("name, lvl", "productsma", "id=3", "", "", "Errore nei risultati");
        print_r($query);
        break;
}
}

$value = $_POST["value"];
provaAJAX($value);
```

Comment: You need to send a JSON response to do that

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks for the answer Patrick, but what do you mean? Is there not in jQuery a simple and clear way like in PHP, similar to `data[0]["name"]`?

Comment: There is.  But as I said, you need to send the data back as JSON, not text.  You said that you read all of the questions about multidimensional arrays. Great.  Now you need to do the same for ajax.  There are myriad questions here about sending ajax requests to PHP and creating and handling the response.

Comment: @PatrickQ Great! Now I know what the problem is and I can search for a solution, thanks Patrick